# Performance measure of BufferedReader Vs BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

Recently I have modified my code to

- While taking input form STDIN, I moved from `Scanner` to `BufferedInputStream`.
- I also read about `BufferedReader` which takes the input from any `InputStreamReader`. This `InputStreamReader` can be used with `System.in` to take `STDIN` input.
- `BufferedInputStream` has `read()` method, which further needs to be parsed according to the objective.

In my case first i need to take an integer (let say n) as input from `STDIN` after that a `for loop` will take n strings as input. These strings have at max 1,00,000 characters.

Question is : Which one among `Scanner`, `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedReader` performs better for my objective?

Comment: Have you tried each approach? The easiest way of finding out what performs better is to write prototype programs and performance test them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner was designed to simplify acceptance of input parameters at run time from user. This is the java equivalent of scanf()/getc()/cin. The 'Reader's are used to read character data, 'Stream's for streamed data. Scanner is best suited for your purpose. As it is simple to code and use.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a BufferedReader in your case. It will be much faster than Scanner as your strings have quite a lot of characters.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

//To get an integer
int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

//To get a string.
String line = br.readLine()
```